# I would like to set div width relative to its height

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to set the width of a div relative to its own height?

i.e.

```
.classname {
    width: 40%;
    height: calc(width * 0.67);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css) details many ways on how to maintain the aspect ratio of an HTML element. A simple, modern solution uses the CSS `aspect-ratio` property:

```css
div.relative-width {
  height: 200px;
  background: gold;
  
  /*  set width to always be half of height */
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative-width">
  <p>This div is 200px high, and the width should be half of that: 100px</p>
</div>
```

Comment: don't repeat previous answers if you know they exist. Flag as duplicate or add a comment so we can close the question